# GC installed new front door with huge beads of sealant that is dripping

Tags: doors, installation, door-frame, contractors, sealant

Just as my title suggests, we hired contractors to measure, fabricate, and install doors for us. We want to know if we should demand that they fix the issue? We also want to know if it is a simple fix? Thank you.

They gave us a quote with exact measurements of the door that they would provide and we paid $4,500 to have the work done.

The installers arrive with the doors, but the door itself is a few inches smaller than what was quoted. In the image, the height of the door is 109", but the total height of the door is 105". As a result, the transom glass has a much different size than the images in the quote. It's less rectangular.

We also noticed during the installation that when the installers positioned the door, there was more than 3" of gap along the side and top of the door compared to the door opening. As a result, they needed to add a lot of weatherproofing foam surrounding the door frame on the interior.

Now, the problem we have is with the exterior. In order to fill the gap between the door and the brick, they added a ~2" bead of sealant around the edges of the exterior door frame. It looked larger than the bead used on our neighbor's doors. The bead was also not pressed or smoothed out (like our neighbor's), so it has a 2" semicircular appearance.

We inquired about the size of the bead and we asked the installers to smooth it out for us, but they refused and assured us that the bead would shrink significantly within 10 days. Unfortunately, the bead that runs across the top of the door is starting to become dislodged and it is drooping slightly out of the gap (see image).

Note: The house is over 100 years old, but the doors appear to have been previously replaced at some point.

[image]

Comment: You didn't actually ask us a question. Yes, it looks like a pig of a job. Get them back to fix it.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my post. Do you happen to know what they would need to do? The gap is quite large, I believe.

Comment: If they haven't supplied & fitted what the contract says they should, then of course they need to return & correct it at their expense. You might need a lawyer, though,  more than random opinions from the interwebz.

Comment: Make them take it out and reinstall the door they quoted you for. 3" from the jamb to framing is unacceptable, period. I would absolutely, 100% reject this. Hopefully you haven't paid in full.

Comment: Read the quote over carefully.  If the door(not the door opening) does not match, then this becomes a contract dispute plus bad workmanship.

Comment: Unfortunately, the quote we signed didn't include measurements. They provided the quote along with another document (in th quote package) that had the exact measurements, but we didn't sign it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there was no question asked.

Comment: @FreeMan, `We want to know if we should demand that they fix the issue? We also want to know if it is a simple fix? ` sounds like questions to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insist that they provide you with a door the same size as the measurements they quoted for you. It looks like they "found" a cheap door or had one lying around that they dumped on you.  The gaps you mentioned are way too big. 2" wide beads of caulk are ridiculous and of course they will droop.

Comment: We checked the documents they sent us and the quote we signed didn't include measurements for the door. They did include another document in the "quote package" that had all of the measurements, but it was not something that we signed. Do we still have a case?

Comment: If the measurements in the document they provided as part of the quote are different than the measurements of the door they installed, they should be held accountable.  Online negative reviews are a great bargaining chip.